# Can the big five personality dimensions be trained/enhanced?

Tags: educational-psychology, big-five

Are there established methods to, say, enhance someone's conscientiousness or agreeableness? In particular, since it seems there's evidence linking positive relationship between [the big five to academic and workplace performance](https://www.ets.org/s/workforce_readiness/pdf/21334_big_5.pdf), is there a way to enhance these five traits in students either in primary/secondary education or higher education?

Comment: All of the big five terms cover a huge range of behaviors, attitudes, and social interactions. And some of them are very simple. You could, in Big Five's own terms, increase agreeableness by being more cooperative or trusting. Which could be a huge step for some or a minor one for others. I'm going to suggest you narrow down this question to a specific  trait or portion of a trait,

Comment: @ReedRawlings, you have a point. I was looking for cursory answers  whether such training exist or not in any one of the five. It seems like quite fertile ground for research (and business) given how established the big five is, I'm surprised that I couldn't find literature on the subject, or even 'snake oil' methods claiming to enhance the big five.I think I'll just propose to close this question instead.

Comment: There is a lot of research on those individual traits and characteristics. Self-control, optimism, grit, open-mindedness, mindset, extroversion. This includes ways to train or enhance those traits. You'll just have to be specific when searching. So to answer your question, yes.